# How check string starts with number count in XSLT

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

Input:

```
<para>
    <text>1. this a paragaraph1</text>
    <text>12. this a paragaraph2</text>
    <text>2. this a paragaraph2</text>
    <text>this a paragaraph3</text>
</para>
```

My current output:

```
<result>
    <para type="number">1. this a paragaraph1</para>
    <para type="number">12. this a paragaraph2</para>
    <para type="number">2. this a paragaraph2</para>
    <para type="not number">this a paragaraph3</para>
</result>
```

Output should be:

```
<result>
    <para type="number">1. this a paragaraph1</para>
    <para type="number double">12. this a paragaraph2</para>
    <para type="number">2. this a paragaraph2</para>
    <para type="not number">this a paragaraph3</para>
</result>
```

Explanation of the logic:

You can see `para/text` has a string. Some of them are starting with numbers (`1.`  , `12.` ) then `.` and space. At that time `para/@type` must be `number`. If the count of that number is `1` @type should be `number`. If the count of that number is `2` @type should be `number double`. You can see the example.

Tried code:

```
<xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="matches(.,'^[0-9]+\. ')">
            <para type="number">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </para>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <para type="not number">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </para>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="para">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

I am using `XSLT 2.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="matches(., '^\d{2}\. ')">double</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="matches(., '^\d\. ')">number</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>not number</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```